# Prove or provide a counterexample indicating whether the following statements are true or false.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove or provide a counterexample indicating whether the following statements are true or false.

$a)$ If $P(A)=P(B)$ then $P(A\Delta B)=0$

$b)$ If $P(A\Delta B)=0$ then $P(A)=P(B)$

$c)$ $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)\cdot P(B)$

My intuition tells me that:

$a)$ FALSE

$b)$ TRUE

$c)$ FALSE

For $a)$ and $c)$ I have a counterexample. To prove $b)$, if $P(A\Delta B)=P(A-B)+P(B-A)$ or $P(A\Delta B)=P(A\cup B)-P(A\cap B)$, I can't get anything.

Comment: c) is false. Take $A=B$.

Comment: go beyond intuition, write down your reasoning if possible

Comment: Please make the title informative as to the *mathematical content* of the post, rather than what you hope people will do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a). Let the probability space be $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\lambda)$. We have $\lambda([0,0.25])=\lambda([0.05,0.3])=0.25$ but $\lambda([0,0.05)\cup (0.25,0.3])=0.1 \neq 0$.

(b). We have
$$P(A\Delta B)=P((A/B)\cup(B/A))=P(A\cap B^c)+P(B\cap A^c)=0$$
$$P(A\cap B^c),P(B\cap A^c)= 0 \implies P(A)=P(A\cap B)+\underbrace{P(A\cap B^c)}_{=0} \textrm{ and } \\ P(B)=P(A\cap B)+\underbrace{P(B \cap A^c)}_{=0} \implies P(A) =P(B)$$

(c). Let the probability space be $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\lambda)$. We have $\lambda([0,0.25])=\lambda([0.05,0.3])=0.25$ but $\lambda([0.05,0.25])=0.2 > 0.25^2=0.0625$.

Comment: For part (b) we cannot conclude that $A=B$.  Similarly, if $P[C]=0$ we cannot conclude $C$ is the empty set.

Comment: @Michael thank you. it's fixed now.